# path.home is not configured in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: path.home is not configured
    at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.(Environment.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:152)
    at JavaAPIMain.main(JavaAPIMain.java:43)

//adding document to elasticsearch using java

```
    Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("myapplication").node();
Client client = node.client();

        client.prepareIndex("kodcucom", "article", "1")
              .setSource(putJsonDocument("ElasticSearch: Java",
                                         "ElasticSeach provides Java API, thus it executes all operations " +
                                          "asynchronously by using client object..",
                                         new Date(),
                                         new String[]{"elasticsearch"},
                                         "Hüseyin Akdoğan")).execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this one:

```
NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
    .settings(Settings.builder()
        .put("path.home", "/path/to/elasticsearch/home/dir")
    .node();
```

Credits: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15325

Always ask Google about your error message first. There are more than 5k results for your problem.

Comment: After adding those line I got node undefine error.Error is The method node() is undefined for the type

Answer (score 0):

if you are using intellij or eclipse,
edit configuration and add the below line in your VMoptions

-Des.path.home={dropwizard installation directory}

for example in my mac

-Des.path.home=/Users/supreeth.vp/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin